React Native expo-gl CMake tries to use arm64-v8 despite me being on x86_84
My React Native ExpoGL project is failing with the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-gl:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1210] /home/fredrik/Downloads/roise/integrasjonsprosjekt/frontend/node_modules/expo-gl/android/CMakeLists.txt debug|arm64-v8a : No compatible library found

Im expecting Cmake to build for x86_64 and not ARM when thats what my pc supports. Ive tried reinstalling deps a million times, running npx expo-doctor, fixing deps, reinstalling my entire os, java, setting all paths, but even after doing all of that, I still get the same error.
